# Settings button in navigation bar

Tags: java, android

I have been with this issue for days, I tried everything, someone know how to achieve the right settings button ?Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was deprecated ages ago. You are supposed to use ActionBar buttons/menus instead.

You can learn more about ActionBar in
[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html).

---

Here's an example of how this can look on Android 4.x:

[image: Menu example]